# How can I execute a PHP script with a Javascript variable on a Js button click?

Tags: php, javascript, database, button, textfield

I would like to run a PHP segment of code with veriables from a Javascript text field while using that veriable in the PHP function. All of that should be executed with a Javascript button click.

`[Js Text] --> Js button click --> veriable --> PHP (MySQL DB)`

An attached sample code would be grand.

Thanks.

Comment: Its called ajax. Do some more research and come back with a more specific question.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest%2FUsing_XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**KEYWORD: AJAX** (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML).
With jQuery you can perform a `POST` request to a PHP script and receive a response.

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
    .done(function(data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

PS:
In your PHP you can use: `$_POST['name']`/`$_POST['time']` to request these variables.

Answer (score 0):

use ajax...if you are using jquery check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
and for running the ajax event look for the click event @
http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way to execute php by js, because the process of interpreting a php webpage is as follows:

`php server ==generate==> html files ==webbrowser execute==> JS`

You just cannot go back to the first stage in js. Also the js is executed at your browser rather than the server.

To do your work, you should write a new php page that execute the desired action and call this page using JS.

Also, I assume you are just calling Database, and you can definately find other ways to link to database via JS.