# How to call a function when ok button in alert box clicked in php-mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

```
function warn(warning) {

  alert(warning);
  capturedAlert();

}

function capturedAlert() {

  alert('An alert was called.');

}
```

//not like this, i just want to perform update or insert when we click on the alert ok button, is that possible?

Comment: You need to send a request to a PHP script using ajax to make server side changes.

Comment: You need to listen for the click event on the button and then use ajax to call the php file or route.  This is a duplicate of several questions, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922687/how-can-i-execute-a-php-script-with-a-javascript-variable-on-a-js-button-click

Answer (score 1):

You can use confirm, which returns a boolean if the user clicks "Ok" and false if he clicks "Cancel"

```
if (confirm('Some question ?')) {
  console.log('executing method')
}
```